# How can we create docker image from local Keycloak Distribution folder?

Tags: keycloak

I have made all the necessary changes which are required for my project in my local keycloak distribution. Now, I want to create docker image of my local keycloak distribution folder (which I downloaded from keycloak website).

Comment: Why you want to create from you local distribution,  it will become difficult for you  to upgrade. For every upgrade you need to do same changes. It is advised to get image from repo like docker hub and then apply changes after running the keycloak.

Comment: @ravthiru - if the customer is doing the deployment say on a Kubernetes cluster, then they might be expecting a customized docker image so that they can start the pods. So I believe there are situations where you need to customize the docker images.

Comment: You need to create docker file which uses keycloak image and initialisation script to customise the keycloak and generate image from that.

Comment: Maybe this can be used as an example https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/docker/import_realm_users/Dockerfile